# Set value of struts-2 iterator with ajax response list

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, iterator

I am using `struts-2 iterator` in my jsp page:

```
<s:iterator var="campListIterator" value="campList">
            <h3><s:property /></h3>
            <div class="acc">
                //Some content
            </div>
</s:iterator>
```

But, my `campList` is comming through jquery-ajax response. How can I use this list for iteration?

Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "getCampData",
        data: {campaignId: campaignId},
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Camp List : " + data.campList);
        //$('#iterator').val(data.campList);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are receiving list in your ajax response? If so, What you want to do with your list? I mean what is your expected output? What is the output you are getting in alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On thing I can suggest is dont get result through ajax call if you want to use struts-iterator. All you have to do is just put the campList in valuestack in your ajax call and when you return back,list will be iterated hopefully. This [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_value_stack_ognl.htm) might help you achieve one. :)